# Connect negative terminal of a battery to Earth

Tags: batteries, current, battery-charging, electromagnetism

I have a question about what happens
in following experiment: Assume we have
a battery with two Galvanic half cell,
eg. a magnesium anode and a copper cathode.
Since copper has higher electrode potential
that magnesium, the electrode with
magnesium oxidizes and therefore becomes
the negative terminal und the electrode
with copper reduces and becomes
positive terminal.

I want to find out what happens at the
moment when we connect the earth only to the negative terminal, leaving the positive terminal disconnected? Does there happen a very short electrostatic discharge immediately after connection such that the electrons sitting in the magnesium chunk get absorbed by the earth?
(the earth is here considered as
electrostatically neutral uncharged source
with constant potential, which can
absorb und donate a huge amount of
electrons without changing it's potential) See also this image:

[image]

Question: What happens at the moment we
connect the negative terminal
(magnesium) having excess of electrons with
earth und leave simultaneously the positive terminal
unconnected?

Clearly, since the positive terminal is
unconnected, there cannot establish a steady
current because there is no closed circuit between positive and negative terminals. Therefore such connection will surely not drain completely the battery, but the question is if it could happen that only the burst of electrons which *actually* inhabiting the magnesium anode going be absorbed by the earth and then everything stops.

But I'm primary interested in electrostatic effects and want to know
if there happens a electrostatic discharge at the contact moment within a very very short moment sending the excess electrons from negative terminal
to earth or does there really literally
'nothing' happen?

Why I conjecture that such elecrostatic discharge should happen. At the moment when we connect
the earth to the magnesium electrode seemingly the unconnected copper electrode isn't noticed by the system earth-magnesium electrode since we assumed that there is no connection to the copper electrode:

[image]

And since the earth is neatrally charged and the magnesium electrode contains a lot of electrons on it, it seems reasonable that all this electrons 'want' to run into the neutral earth at the moment we connect the earth to the magnesium electrode. Does it sound reasonable.

That seems to be quite similar to the question what happens immediately after we connect the positive to negative terminals of two Galvanic half cells but remove the salt bridge:

[image]

Again, clearly without salt bridge there can no consistent current happen because the salt bridge closes the circuit as ion conductor.

But nevertheless, at the moment we connect the two terminals/electrods whith a wire, shouldn't the excessed electrons at magnesium electrode not nevertheless flow to copper electode and then stay there to compensate the charge/potential difference? And only then because due to lack of salt bridge everything stops?

Are my reasonings correct or if not what is my error? (I asked the same question [in physicsstack](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/661200/connect-negative-terminal-of-a-battery-to-earth/661221?noredirect=1#comment1483510_661221)

Answer (score 2):

Conncting two objects together,  like earth and your circuit, in a way that does not close a loop will pretty much do nothing after connecting them.

When you connect two objects together, they will be at the same potential. If they originally were not at equal potential, it means that there was charge between them, and connecting the wire will discharge the potential difference quite rapidly as charges redistribute.

There will be no electrons or current flowing after that.

In order to have a flow of current, you need a loop with a potential difference.

Same way, a lamp lights up if you connect it to the both terminals of a say 12V battery. Connecting one of the battery terminals (pick either of them) to earth will do nothing special. There will still be 12V between battery terminals, and current will only flow through the lamp if it is connected to battery terminals. And one of the terminals will be connected to earth, setting the circuit potentials in reference to earth.

Same idea with a 3 meter stick. If you have a 3 meter stick, it will still be a 3 meter stick, at the ground level, at the bottom of the sea, or on top of a mountain. Setting where the reference level is has no effect on the stick.

Comment: Yes, of course there will no permanent current as long as there is
no closed loop in the circuit. But I'm only interested in momentary electrostatic
effects, discharge effect which might happen immediately after connecting 
the negative terminal to the earth. On what happens after that, I totally agree
with you, later there nothing happens by same argument since my two experiments
not contain a closed loop.

Comment: But the question of my interest is what happens at the instant we connect the earth to the negative teminal?
First of all the negative terminal aka a Galvanic half cell consists
of a magnesium bar dipped into the electrolyte solution, a mixture of 
MgSO_4 and water. Since magnesium is quite reactive some of the magnesium
atoms in the bar give up their two electons and dissolve in the solution 
as Mg++ ions.

Comment: So the bar becomes negative charged (since contains some electons)
and the electrolyte solution becomes positively charged due to
dissolved Mg++ ions. If we now connect the neutrally charged earth to the 
magnesium bar, shouldn't some electrons be absorbed be absorbed by the 
earth, or are they "fixed" strong enough at the surface of the bar by 
positive Mg++ ions, such that they cannot "go away into the earth"?

Answer (score 1):

Initially there is a small current (that has very little to do with the battery, but more from natural potential differences any two objects have a potential difference between them), which you could think of as static being equalized.

After that, nothing happens, except for a very very small current traveling through the air and back to ground through the battery, the circuit looks like this so it would be less than pico amps traveling through the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDAbc7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As far as the salt bridge, it would look something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzGwnx.png)</sup>

So unless you have a meter that can measure the resistance of air (most stop at 10^7 or 10^8 ohms) you won't see a current and it will register on the volt meter as open.

Comment: Could you elaborate in more detail the "Initially there is a small current"
part? That's exactly I'm looking for in this question (since of
course as long as there is nowhere a loop in the circuit, no permanent
current can flow). Let's talk for the first about first experiment where
we connect the negative terminal to earth. When we but the magnesium bar
into the electrolyte solution some of magesium atoms give up their
two electrons and dissolve as Mg++ ions in the solution.

Comment: So the 
magnesium bar contains certain amount of nagatively charged electons 
in it (see picture 2) and we connect now the earth to it. he question is what precisely is your
"Initially there is a small current" there. That some of these electons 
are absorbed by the earth? On the other hand how strong is the
force of the dissolved Mg++ ions swimming in the solution. 
Do they completely prevent the electons in the magnesium bar to flow
to earth or not?

Comment: I should have clarified that, there's a small flow of electrons, but if you connect any two conductors in the physical world there is a small flaw of electrons because almost never are no two objects are at the same potential (they might be close). It's got nothing to do with the battery, but more to do with its probably not the same potential